# BitBlting with Windows Aero

Tags: vb.net, aero, bitblt

For months now, I have been trying to solve a problem regarding rendering images properly onto Aero glass. From what I have gathered so far, to do this you need to render the graphics object as a bitmap, because the Aero requires an alpha channel. To be more specific, what I am trying to do is make a perfect, non-flicker text box ( and other controls). I do not want to fall back to rendering part of the form aero, as I may want more than one text box. Also, the DrawToBitmap function works, but is far too slow, which is why I want to accomplish this with BitBlt.

What I have right now, is the Graphics control of a TextBox, stored as a IntPtr. How do I take this graphics control, load it into a Bitmap, and draw that Bitmap with BitBlt? (or as the link suggests, fixing the alpha value of the Graphics object)

So my question is, is there anyway to do this with Visual Basic 2010 .NET?

If anyone can answer this question, provide input, or a equivalent alternative, I'd be very grateful.

Here is a link to a previous thread I have made, which describes the problem in much more detail:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/f0e9fa0c-9535-4cdb-826f-673ef58c408a

Best regards,

- Jake M.

P. S.

This link has helped greatly, and addresses my problem. However the solution on the very last post seems to be what I am looking for, however I have no idea how to convert that into visual basic.

[Aero: How to draw solid (opaque) colors on glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass)