# WinAPI - Blurring a window fails

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, gdi

I want to blur a window, and I have used `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow()`, `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` and `DwmSetWindowAttribute()` (to enable the client area rendering). However, it fails to blur, and instead makes the client area white.

Minimum reproducible code:

```c
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HWND hwnd;

HRESULT enableNCRendering(HWND hWnd)
{
    enum DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;

    HRESULT hr = DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd,
                               DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
                               &ncrp,
                               sizeof(ncrp));

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Failed 0\n");
    return hr;
}

HRESULT EnableBlurBehind(HWND hwnd)
{
    DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = {0};

    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE;
    bb.fEnable = true;
    bb.hRgnBlur = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, &bb);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Failed 1\n");
    return hr;
}

HRESULT ExtendIntoClientAll(HWND hwnd)
{
    MARGINS margins = {-1};
    HRESULT hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Failed 2\n");
    return hr;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCWSTR name, UINT styles, COLORREF bkg_colour, WNDPROC proc)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style = styles;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = proc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(hInst, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(bkg_colour); // CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0))
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIconW(hInst, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)name;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wc);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCAPTION;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance, L"Main", CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS, RGB(255, 0, 0), WndProc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_LAYERED, L"Main", L"main", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1000, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hwnd)
        return 1;
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 100, LWA_ALPHA);

    enableNCRendering(hwnd);
    EnableBlurBehind(hwnd);
    ExtendIntoClientAll(hwnd);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

I have also tried `SetWindowCompositionAttributes()` but it was undefined in Mingw, and I wasn't able to find much information on using that. It also doesn't give the desired effect and gives barely any blur:

[image]

```c
#include <Winerror.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HWND hwnd;

struct ACCENTPOLICY
{
    int na;
    int nf;
    int nc;
    int nA;
};
struct WINCOMPATTRDATA
{
    int na;
    PVOID pd;
    ULONG ul;
};

typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pSetWindowCompositionAttribute)(HWND, WINCOMPATTRDATA*);

void makeBlur()
{
    const HINSTANCE hm = LoadLibraryW(L"user32.dll");
    if (hm)
    {
        const pSetWindowCompositionAttribute SetWindowCompositionAttribute = (pSetWindowCompositionAttribute)GetProcAddress(hm, "SetWindowCompositionAttribute");
        if (SetWindowCompositionAttribute)
        {
            struct ACCENTPOLICY policy = {3, 0, 0, 0};
            struct WINCOMPATTRDATA data = {19, &policy, sizeof(ACCENTPOLICY)};
            SetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, &data);
        }
        FreeLibrary(hm);
    }
}
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCWSTR name, UINT styles, COLORREF bkg_colour, WNDPROC proc)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style = styles;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = proc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(hInst, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(bkg_colour); // CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0))
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIconW(hInst, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)name;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wc);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCAPTION;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    //getting accent colors
    DWORD color = 0;
    BOOL opaque = FALSE;
    DwmGetColorizationColor(&color, &opaque);

    BYTE blue = color;

    color = color >> 8;
    BYTE green = color;
    
    color = color >> 8;
    BYTE red = color;

    color = color >> 8;
    BYTE alpha = color;

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance, L"Main", CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS, RGB(red, green, blue), WndProc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_LAYERED, L"Main", L"main", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1000, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hwnd)
        return 1;
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 100, LWA_ALPHA);

    makeBlur();

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

How can I make my window blur?

Comment: I don't see how c++ is relevant here. Winapi is a plain c API. Removed the tag.

Comment: What are the actual `HRESULT` values that are being returned when the functions fail?

Comment: Does Windows even support blurring any more? I thought they ditched that.

Comment: I think its dead. Windows 8 killed Aero and it never returned.

Comment: @RemyLebeau They all return 0, which is supposed to be `S_OK`

Comment: @Anders is there any other way for me to get a similar effect?

Comment: @SKNG in Win10+, you must use `SetWindowCompositionAttributes()`. If you are having trouble using it, update your question to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow) states:

> Beginning with Windows 8, **calling this function doesn't result in the blur effect**, due to a style change in the way windows are rendered.

Aero Glass was officially discontinued in Windows 8. However, Aero Glass made a comeback (sort of) in Windows 10, as the Taskbar and some system notifications still use it. You have to use the *undocumented* `SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` API to enable the blur effect now, see:

[How do you set the glass blend colour on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724187/)

You are looking for the `ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND` option.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it with the issue of SetWindowCompositionAttribute().