# Aero: How to draw ClearType text on glass?

Tags: aero, cleartype, aero-glass

Using GDI+ to draw text on glass:

```
graphics.DrawString(s, Length(s), font, MakePointF(x, y), brush);
```

You'll notice that the ClearType enabled text draws **very** poorly on glass:

[image]

But with glass disabled the text, of course, draw fine:

[image]

By way of comparison here is **Anti-alias font smoothing**:

[image]

And here is **no font smoothing**:

[image]

**Note**: No font smoothing looks better than it really does because StackOverflow resizes the images on your monitor.

How do i draw ClearType text on glass?

### Notes

- Win32 native
- not .NET (*i.e.* native)
- not Winforms (*i.e.* native)
- GDI+ (*i.e.* native)

---

What Mark is suggesting is that you cannot honor the user's preferences for text rendering (i.e. "`SystemDefault`". ClearType does not function on glass, and you cannot use it.

In other words, if you're rendering on glass you must override the text rendering with:

```
graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAliasGridFit);
```

Otherwise you should leave the `TextRenderingHint` at it's default `TextRenderingHintSystemDefault`.

### See also

- [Aero: How to draw solid colors on glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-colors-on-glass)
- [Windows Aero: What color to paint to make “glass” appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870139/windows-aero-what-color-to-paint-to-make-glass-appear)
- [WPF: Extending glass into client area disables ClearType entirely](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/502846/wpf-extending-glass-into-client-area-disables-cleartype-entirely?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inherent to the way drawing is performed. All of your text is being drawn on a black background, then composited onto a glass background; the semi-transparent font smoothing is being combined with black to make near-black.

Comment: The answer you're saying is "you cannot, you must force anti-alias font smoothing". Accepted.