# GDI+: Why is FillRectangle transparent on glass, while FillEllipse is opaque?

Tags: gdi+, aero, dwm

i'm drawing a rectangle, and an ellipse, on glass.

```
brush = new SolidBrush(0xFF000000); //solid (i.e. non-opaque) black
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x,    y,    30, 30);
graphics.FillEllipse(brush,   x+33, y-15, 30, 30);
```

- drawing with ellipse: it's **opaque**
- drawing with rectangle: it's **not** opaque

[image]

What is going on here?

You can see the same also applies for other colors:

```
brush = new SolidBrush(0xFFff0000); //solid (i.e. non-opaque) red
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y,    30, 30);
graphics.FillEllipse(brush,   x, y+33, 30, 30);

brush = new SolidBrush(0xFF00ff00); //solid (i.e. non-opaque) green
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y,    30, 30);
graphics.FillEllipse(brush,   x, y+33, 30, 30);

brush = new SolidBrush(0xFF0000ff); //solid (i.e. non-opaque) blue
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y,    30, 30);
graphics.FillEllipse(brush,   x, y+33, 30, 30);

brush = new SolidBrush(0xFFffffff); //solid (i.e. non-opaque) white
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y,    30, 30);
graphics.FillEllipse(brush,   x, y+33, 30, 30);
```

[image]

**Conclusion**: Why does:

- `FillEllipse` with an opaque color draw opaque
- `FillRectangle` with an opaque color draws partially transparent

> **Note:** This question is very nearly a duplicate of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass).
>   Except this question focuses on the
>   difference between `FillRectangle` and
>   `FillEllipse` - whereas that question
>   deals with *How to draw opaque colors
>   on glass.

### See also

- [Aero: How to draw solid (opaque) colors on glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass)
- [Windows Aero: What color to paint to make “glass” appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870139/windows-aero-what-color-to-paint-to-make-glass-appear)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am getting the same thing.